# What does "prominent chin" mean?

Tags: meaning

Does it mean :

1. Big chin(area of chin is huge)?
2. Chubby face?
3. Strong and noticeable jaw line?

When used in a book, does it in certain way means the girl is not so good looking?
The usage from Rowling in this case is definitely not describing someone beautiful.

> A lantern came swinging towards Harry and by its light he saw the **prominent chin** and severe haircut of Professor Grubbly-Plank, the witch who had taken over Hagrid's Care of Magical Creatures lessons for a while the previous year.

Comment: This comment was closed by five people who cited the "entirely answerable with a dictionary" reason. I looked up _prominent_ in the dictionary, and found the dictionary is unable to hone the definition down much more than the O.P. has in this question (see [Macmillan](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/prominent), e.g.; a "prominent chin" could be one that sticks out, or one that is easy to see and notice). Based on the three possibilities cited by the O.P., I'm assuming the O.P. already has consulted a dictionary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means the chin sticks out from the jaw.

> **Prominent**
>   projecting from something; protuberant.

[Example](http://www.youthink.com/quiz_images/quiz819outcome2.jpg)